# difference between "mechanism driver" and "extension driver" in openstack

Tags: cloud, openstack

could anyone explain me what is the difference between "mechanism driver" and "extension driver" in openStack.
I didnt find any document or information related to it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A mechanism driver create, update, and delete
networks and ports.

An extension driver extends the core resources implemented by the
ML2 plugin with additional attributes. Methods that process create
and update operations for these resources validate and persist
values for extended attributes supplied through the API as can be port_security, this extension let you create instances who route traffic avoiding anti-spoofing rules at iptables defined by neutron.